# Where to place logic when extracting data from database in mvvm pattern, using android room?

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, repository, android-room

I am refactoring old application to mvvm pattern, using room, repository, viewmodel, ets.

I have an old code, which contains Content provider helper class with many functions like this:

```java
    public static int deleteOldLogs(int NumDays) {
    //get NumDays before today, then constract a content provider delete command and run
    ...
    }
or 
public static Cursor getTodayLogs() {
    //get a day from today, then constract a content provider query and run
        ...
    }
or
    public static boolean isActionValid(Context context, int id_order, int id_actionh) {
    //get all products from database table, then check if all products match some criteria, then return boolean result
    ...
    }
```

My question is in what layer to place this logic? Is it a repository or viewmodel should contain? All the examples that I see in the net is very simple and not suit my goals.

Answer (score 0):

View model helps us to provide data between repository and UI . For direct interaction with room database , we use repository . Once we get the data from repo we can perform all sort of computation (i.e sorting , filtering etc ) in ViewModel .

In order to  display data from the database, we use an observer who will observe the data changes, LiveData in the ViewModel.

We use ViewModelProvider which is going to create a ViewModel for us. We need to connect our ViewModel with the ViewModelProvider, and then in the onChanged method, we always get our updated data which we can display on the screen.

For eg . We want to  get some record from our database .

For this we need to create a repository that will interact directly with database or carrying the logic to fetch data from database .

```
public class ABCRepository {

@Inject
DrugsDao mABCDao;

@Inject
public ABCRepository(){

}

public LiveData<List<NameModel>> getNameByLetter(String letter) {
    return mABCDao.getName(letter);
}
}
```

Now in View Model

```
public class SearchViewModel extends ViewModel {

@Inject
ABCRepository mABCRepository;

LiveData<List<GlobalSearchModel>> getNameList(String queryText) {
    MutableLiveData<List<GlobalSearchModel>> mGlobalSearchResults = new 
  MutableLiveData<>();

    List<NameModel> synonymsNameList=mABCRepository.getNameByLetter(queryText);

   new Thread(() -> {
        List<GlobalSearchModel> globalSearchModelList =         
        mABCRepository.getNameByLetter(queryText)

       // this is where you can perform any action on list . either sorting or. 
       filtering and then return the new list to your UI.



        mGlobalSearchResults.postValue(globalSearchModelList);

        }).start();


    return globalSearchModelList;
}

}
```

In your fragment or activity you can observe this data ,

```
            getViewModel().getAllCountries().observe(this, this::addSearchResultsInRecycler);
```

Hope this is helpful . Though not explained good but you can have reference from

https://medium.com/@skydoves/android-mvvm-architecture-components-using-the-movie-database-api-8fbab128d7